# Creating http video stream using libVLC

Tags: http, video, libvlc

I have a video that I want to broadcast on a network using the http protocol.
I know libVLC can do that but I haven't been able to know how. I checked the doxygen documentation, but this hasn't helped me. Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: doxygen documentation is for the code itself. You need to understand the product first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libvlc is the library to develop the application. vlc player is the client AND SERVER application to do that. If you just need to stream, use vlc media player as a server. You can find the command line / GUI steps if you google "vlc how to stream".

Basically in the file open dialog you get the option to configure either to load a stream from another source or local file OR RUN your own application as a streaming server.

The play button at the bottom of open dialog has a small button on the right to selec "stream" instead of play. But you need to have configured all options correctly to setup the type of stream you are looking for.

Lastly, you can run another instance of vlc as client to test your stream locally.